# How to validate document ids which are generated by spring-data-elasticsearch

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

How to validate document ids (for length and format, using a regex or something equivalent) which are generated by spring-data-elasticsearch for each document. For example

```
ko9aCXYBBPcZl3qx_3HQ
hI9RCXYBBPcZl3qx93FG
```

Comment: what do you want to validate them for? They are generated by Elasticsearch with the `org.elasticsearch.common.UUIDs` class, check the source here : https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/v7.10.0/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/index/IndexRequest.java#L684-L697. So what be invalid for you?

Comment: All REST calls expect this id as input while trying to fetch a document, if they pass an UUID missing a character or any other random string would it be possible that it is not in the structure of an UUID